# How to store values to a class from ten differents fragments and Retrive the values from the class to an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am doing an experiment. I have 10 fragments one Activity and one java class. I want to send data to the class from 10 different fragments (10 variable for 10 fragments) and then get all values from the class to the activity. I am trying to send a value to the class by using the object like

```
`Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
calculate.a_variable = value;`
```

and trying to receive the value from the class to the activity by,

```
Calculate Calculate = new Calculate();
textview.setText(calculate.a_variable)
```

But I am getting null value in this way.

Comment: Singleton. Shared preferences. SQLite. EventBus. Callbacks. Look into any of these.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by **@Raj** in other answer that is the problem with your code and making singleton will solve your problem but if you want to have more cleaner code and better approach you should use `EventBus` by greenrobot.

You can add it with following dependency:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Then in you Activity class subscribe to the changes with the following code:

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(ModelValue modelValue) {
        Log.d("output", String.valueOf(modelValue.getA()));
    }
```

And from your various fragments you can post values as following:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ModelValue(4f));
            }
        });
```

Here `ModelValue` is my POJO class, you can create yours according to your needs.

For more info on `EventBus` :
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Calculate` class is having different instances so you cannot get values of variable correctly. You must have singleton pattern for `Calculate` class - so that whenever you access `Calculate` class you have single instance and you can get desired values. Please refer this link https://www.javatpoint.com/singleton-design-pattern-in-java for singleton and implement that logic for `Calculate` class.